# Resolution for The configuration :projectname:classpathCopy was resolved without accessing the project in a safe manner

Tags: java, gradle, automation, build.gradle, devops

I am authoring a multiproject build for gradle for the first time. I have written build files for all subprojects and everything is working fine. But when I enable `org.gradle.parallel=true` in `gradle.properties` file and run my build with `--warning-mode=all` I receive warnings such as

```
The configuration :UtilTest:testImplementationCopy2 was resolved without accessing the project in a safe manner.  This may happen when a configuration is resolved from a different project. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sub:resolving-unsafe-configuration-resolution-errors for more details.
The configuration :UtilTest:testRuntimeCopy was resolved without accessing the project in a safe manner.  This may happen when a configuration is resolved from a different project. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sub:resolving-unsafe-configuration-resolution-errors for more details.
The configuration :UtilTest:testRuntimeOnlyCopy was resolved without accessing the project in a safe manner.  This may happen when a configuration is resolved from a different project. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sub:resolving-unsafe-configuration-resolution-errors for more details.
The configuration :UtilTest:testRuntimeOnlyCopy2 was resolved without accessing the project in a safe manner.  This may happen when a configuration is resolved from a different project. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sub:resolving-unsafe-configuration-resolution-errors for more details.
The configuration :UtilTest:classpathCopy was resolved without accessing the project in a safe manner.  This may happen when a configuration is resolved from a different project. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sub:resolving-unsafe-configuration-resolution-errors for more details.
```

UtilTest project is not consumed by any other project.

In other projects I have referenced sibling projects as

A/build.gradle

```
plugins {
 id "war" 
id "Java" 
} 
dependencies {
   implementation project(":B")
}
```

B/build.gradle

```
plugins {
id "Java-library" 
}
```

A is a`war` project, B is a shared library and does not depend on any other project and UtilTest is command line application depending on B

UtilTest/gradle.build

```
plugins {
id "Java-application" 
} 

dependencies {
implementation project(":B“) 
}
```

I have tried to solve this by providing custom configuraions in project B without any success.

Comment: What plugins are you using? How is UtilTest related to A and B?

Comment: Edited post. Please see